# TestNG-java.lang.AbstractMethodError:org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNG6_9_10$DelegatingTestRunnerFactory

Tags: java, eclipse, testng

I am getting the below error while executing my testng test case. I have upgraded TestNg Eclipse plugin as 6.11.0 latest one and using tried with all testng jars files and no luck to resolve this issue.

Am I missing anything here to add my project or else what should I do ?

Someone please help to resolve to this error:

> **java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNG6_9_10$DelegatingTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(Lorg/testng/ISuite;Lorg/testng/xml/XmlTest;Ljava/util/List;)Lorg/testng/TestRunner;**
>     at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner$ProxyTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(SuiteRunner.java:544)
>     at org.testng.SuiteRunner.init(SuiteRunner.java:142)    at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.(SuiteRunner.java:106)   at
>   org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunner(TestNG.java:1116)     at
>   org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunners(TestNG.java:1103)    at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:955)   at
>   org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:900)    at
>   org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
>     at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:230)
>     at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:76)

Comment: Which TestNG version do you have in your project?

Comment: What do you see if enable debug on the launch configuration dialog?

Comment: Hey juherr, As my project is using the 6.3 testng version but when i run with this version then I am getting another error saying "can't recognize the testng version on classpath" . after that I removed it and add the latest jar 6.10 to my project by "Add Library" after that I am getting this above error. I tried so much to resolve it but could not resolve it

Comment: When I create a new project and add the same jar then it is working fine. but I need to do for my project. Please let me help how to do solve this.

Comment: I am using 6.9.10 testng version in my project.

Comment: sorry for responding late, I don't receive any notification about comments. could you double check if you have multi testng jar on your classpath.?       BTW, could we track the issue here: https://github.com/testng-team/testng-remote/issues/42

Answer (score 1):

please add `-verbose:class` to your JVM argument, and identify where the TestNG classes being loaded. see also issue https://github.com/cbeust/testng-eclipse/issues/297

Answer (score 0):

This error occurred when I reinstalled eclipse.

When I downgraded TestNG version from 14 to 10 and to 11, they didn't work.
Eventually I found that eclipse was not uninstalled completely. In "C:\Users\Your AccountName\", three folders exist: *.eclipse*, *.m2* and *.p2*. Delete them and reinstall eclipse, everything goes well.

Answer (score 0):

Above issue is purely TestNG version issue, use TestNG 6.8.3 version(or any appropriate versions), its going to resolve your problem. Clean your project & update project.